# error in implementation of file i/o

Tags: c, linux, file-io, ubuntu-10.04

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int id,q,p,r,a;
    fp = fopen("g-ip.txt","r");
    while(EOF!=fscanf(fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d",&id,&q,&p,&r,&a))
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",id,q,p,r,a);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The format string is so because my g-ip.txt file has values written in the same format. On executing the code, it's giving me wrong output i.e. garbage values which are getting printed infinite times. Should I use arrays to read the values in ?But I don't want to use that.

Comment: Slightly off topic: You do not new to specify whitespace characters in fscanf.

Comment: Has the data file been written on the same computer?

Comment: @steffen: yes the data has been written on the same computer

Comment: OK. that rules out problems with endianity

Comment: I just tried your exact code and it works for me... I compiled with `gcc test.c`

Comment: My code was perfectly fine, there was no error but was not responding correctly before due to the presence of one text line present at the beginning of the file . On removing that , the code worked  :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `feof` and the return count of `fscanf` so try instead something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int id,q,p,r,a;
    fp = fopen("g-ip.txt","r");
    if (!fp) 
      perror("g-ip.txt"), exit(1);
    while(!feof(fp)) {
      id=q=p=r=a=0;
      if (fscanf(fp," %d %d %d %d %d",&id,&q,&p,&r,&a)<5)
        exit(1);
      printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",id,q,p,r,a);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that tabs are same as spaces in `scanf` format strings, no need for `\t\t` there.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int id,q,p,r,a;
    int scanned;
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    fp = fopen("g-ip.txt","r");
    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1,fp))
    {
        scanned = sscanf(buffer,"%d %d %d %d %d",&id,&q,&p,&r,&a));
        if(scanned == 5)
         printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",id,q,p,r,a);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Try this. No need to give '\t'

Comment: If only two integers are parsed by `fscanf` the condition of the `while` is true but the behavior is wrong. You should test `feof`  and the result count of `fscanf` as I proposed.

Comment: Yeah you are right on that. But your `feof` method will read an extra line at the end of the file before it terminates the loop. Prefer to use `fgets` and `sscanf` instead as I have shown in my edit

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `fp` is NULL, either because the file does not exist (executable and file in different directories?) or because the executable does not have permission to open it.

> If the file has been successfully opened the function will return a pointer to a FILE object that is used to identify the stream on all further operations involving it. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

You should check that it is not NULL before using it.

Comment: I checked that too , fp is not empty , please suggest some other solution.

Comment: It is good to test result of `fopen` but since the OP has infinite output that is not the problem. A `NULL` result of `fopen` would have crashed the first call to `fscanf` !

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what exactly is going wrong as you don't post an input line and resulting output line. However, as soon as fscanf fails to match, it'll fail, and more importantly, it'll probably get stuck, continually returning zeros and never finishing. A slightly more resilient solution would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("g-ip.txt","r");
    char enorbuf[2048];
    int errors = 0;

    while (fgets(enorbuf, sizeof(enorbuf), fp) != NULL)
    {
        int id, q, p, r, a;
        if (sscanf(enorbuf, "%d\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d", &id, &q, &p, &r, &a) != 5)
        {
            printf("Invalid input line: %s", enorbuf);
            errors = 1;
        }
        else
        {
             printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", id, q, p, r, a);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return errors ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```